# how to solve IndexError : single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
CODE:-


   from datetime import date
    from datetime import timedelta
    from nsepy import get_history
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    # import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
    
    
    
    end1 = date.today()
    start1 = end1 - timedelta(days=365)
    
    stock = [
             'RELIANCE','HDFCBANK','INFY','ICICIBANK','HDFC','TCS','KOTAKBANK','LT','SBIN','HINDUNILVR','AXISBANK','ITC','BAJFINANCE','BHARTIARTL','ASIANPAINT','HCLTECH','MARUTI','TITAN','BAJAJFINSV','TATAMOTORS',
             'TECHM','SUNPHARMA','TATASTEEL','M&M','WIPRO','ULTRACEMCO','POWERGRID','HINDALCO','NTPC','NESTLEIND','GRASIM','ONGC','JSWSTEEL','HDFCLIFE','INDUSINDBK','SBILIFE','DRREDDY','ADANIPORTS','DIVISLAB','CIPLA',
             'BAJAJ-AUTO','TATACONSUM','UPL','BRITANNIA','BPCL','EICHERMOT','HEROMOTOCO','COALINDIA','SHREECEM','IOC','VEDL','ADANIENT', 'APOLLOHOSP', 'TATAPOWER', 'PIDILITIND', 'SRF', 'NAUKRI', 'ICICIGI', 'DABUR',
             'GODREJCP', 'HAVELLS', 'PEL', 'VOLTAS', 'AUBANK', 'LTI', 'CHOLAFIN', 'AMBUJACEM', 'MARICO', 'SRTRANSFIN','GAIL', 'MCDOWELL-N', 'MPHASIS', 'MINDTREE', 'PAGEIND', 'ZEEL', 'BEL', 'TRENT', 'CROMPTON', 'JUBLFOOD',
             'DLF', 'SBICARD', 'SIEMENS', 'BANDHANBNK', 'IRCTC', 'LAURUSLABS', 'PIIND', 'INDIGO', 'INDUSTOWER','ICICIPRULI', 'MOTHERSON', 'AARTIIND', 'FEDERALBNK', 'BANKBARODA', 'PERSISTENT', 'HINDPETRO', 'ACC',
             'AUROPHARMA', 'COLPAL', 'GODREJPROP', 'MFSL', 'LUPIN', 'BIOCON', 'ASHOKLEY', 'BHARATFORG', 'BERGEPAINT','JINDALSTEL', 'ASTRAL', 'IEX', 'NMDC', 'CONCOR', 'INDHOTEL', 'BALKRISIND', 'PETRONET', 'CANBK', 'ALKEM',
             'DIXON', 'DEEPAKNTR', 'DALBHARAT', 'TVSMOTOR', 'ATUL', 'HDFCAMC', 'TATACOMM', 'MUTHOOTFIN', 'TATACHEM','SAIL', 'IDFCFIRSTB', 'PFC', 'BOSCHLTD', 'MRF', 'NAVINFLUOR', 'CUMMINSIND', 'IGL', 'IPCALAB', 'COFORGE',
             'ESCORTS', 'TORNTPHARM', 'LTTS', 'RECLTD', 'LICHSGFIN', 'BATAINDIA', 'HAL', 'PNB', 'GUJGASLTD', 'UBL','3MINDIA','ABB','AIAENG','APLAPOLLO','AARTIDRUGS','AAVAS','ABBOTINDIA','ADANIGREEN','ATGL','ABCAPITAL',
             'ABFRL','ABSLAMC','ADVENZYMES','AEGISCHEM','AFFLE','AJANTPHARM','ALKYLAMINE','ALLCARGO','AMARAJABAT','AMBER','ANGELONE','ANURAS','APTUS','ASAHIINDIA','ASTERDM','ASTRAZEN','AVANTIFEED','DMART','BASF',
             'BSE','BAJAJELEC','BAJAJHLDNG','BALAMINES','BALRAMCHIN','BANKINDIA','MAHABANK','BAYERCROP','BDL','BEL','BHEL','BIRLACORPN','BSOFT','BLUEDART','BLUESTARCO','BORORENEW','BOSCHLTD','BRIGADE','BCG','MAPMYINDIA'
            ]
  
    
    
    
    
    target_stocks_list = []
    target_stocks = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for stock in stock:
        vol = get_history(symbol=stock,
                      start=start1,
                      end=end1)
    
    
        d_vol = pd.concat([vol['Deliverable Volume']])
        symbol_s = pd.concat([vol['Symbol']])
        close = pd.concat([vol['Close']])
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(symbol_s)
        df['D_vol'] = d_vol
    
        # print(df)
    
    
        cond = df['D_vol'].iloc[-1] > max(df['D_vol'].iloc[-91:-1])
    
        if(cond):
            target_stocks_list.append(stock)
            target_stocks = pd.concat([target_stocks, df])
    
    print(target_stocks_list)
    
    file_name = f'{datetime.datetime.now().day}-{datetime.datetime.now().month}-{datetime.datetime.now().year}.csv'
    target_stocks.to_csv(f'D:/HUGE VOLUME SPURTS/first 250/SEP 2022/{file_name}')
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',10)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows',2000)
    print(target_stocks)
```

ERROR:-

C:\python\Python310\python.exe "C:/Users/Yogesh_PC/PycharmProjects/future oi data analysis/trial2.py"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yogesh_PC\PycharmProjects\future oi data analysis\trial2.py", line 64, in <module>
    cond = df['D_vol'].iloc[-1] > max(df['D_vol'].iloc[-91:-1])
  File "C:\python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1520, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1452, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Above code gives the historical stock data of Indian stock market. The data is updated on website after market closed around 8:00PM to 9:00PM daily. Then I run my code. For most of the days my code gives output without any error but frequently it throws an error which showed above.
There are around 150-200 stocks in my code. This error occurs because some time exchange do not update the data of one or two stocks from the above list that is why this error comes.
So please post the code which will skip the particular one or two stocks which are not updated and should give the output for rest all stocks.
for example:- stocks = ['DLF', 'SBICARD', 'SIEMENS', 'BANDHANBNK', 'IRCTC', 'LAURUSLABS', 'PIIND',
'INDIGO', 'INDUSTOWER','ICICIPRULI', 'MOTHERSON']
in above stocks suppose exchange didn't update the data of 'IRCTC' and rest all stocks are up to date then due to 'IRCTC' my code throws error and it is not showing data which is updated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "out-of-bounds" error indicates you're trying to access a part of the dataframe series that doesn't exist. It's most likely caused by df['D_vol'] being less than 90 items long when you try to do

```
df['D_vol'].iloc[-91:-1]
```

Edit:
add a length check before the offending line:

```
if df['D_vol'].size > 90:
  cond = df['D_vol'].iloc[-1] > max(df['D_vol'].iloc[-91:-1])

  if(cond):
    target_stocks_list.append(stock)
    target_stocks = pd.concat([target_stocks, df])
```

Comment: yes.....So is there any solution through which that particular stock should skip and I should get the rest data of the stocks .

Comment: thank you @Ryo Suzuki it is working fine.